# Chosen jquery plugin for forms - issues getting it to work at it's most basic

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this won't work.  Please refer to jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4YEU2/

Here is the documentation and samples: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a $!!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    **$**(".chzn-select").chosen(); // Missing $ at the beginning of the line in your jsfiddle
});​
```

Comment: wow, ha.  You gotta be kidding me I've been debugging this for HOURS!!!! hahahaha.  Thanks man.  Another set of eyes always helps.

Comment: Pair programming at its best :P